# Variable number of lists in the vector

Tags: scala

trying to create variable number of list in the Vector:

```
val elems = new ListBuffer[String]()
val v = Vector[ListBuffer[String]](elems)
```

Can I specify on creation some kind of the range 0..100 so next number of empty ists will be created in the corresponding vector?

PS. I did try generators but getting a syntax error:

```
val gen  = for(i <- 0 to 100) yield new ListBuffer[String]()
```

Comment: People who downvote. Please comment to tell the reason for downvote. Please. Simply downvoting is of no use. By Commenting you will educate the people who are not good stackoverflow citizens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Vector.fill` to create a filled Vector. Use `List` instead of `ListBuffer`. List is immutable and ListBuffer is mutable

```
Vector.fill(100)(List(1, 2))
```

or

```
Vector.fill(100)(ListBuffer(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: I need mutable type for performance reason. But yes, this is what I am looking. Can't find this in the book :)

Comment: @PavelOliynyk You mean mutable type

Comment: append/prepend operations faster on ListBuffer. Not sure about mutable types in general.